# How can I store a Swift enum value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Environment {
    case Production
    case Staging
    case Dev
}
```

And I'd like to save an instance in NSUserDefaults like this:

```
func saveEnvironment(environment : Environment){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(environment, forKey: kSavedEnvironmentDefaultsKey)
}
```

I understand that a Swift enum isn't an NSObject, and that makes it difficult to save, but I'm unsure what the best way is to convert it to something storable.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Using rawValue for the enum is one way of using types that can be stored in NSUserDefaults, define your enum to use a rawValue. Raw values can be strings, characters, or any of the integer or floating-point number types :

```
enum Environment: String {
    case Production = "Prod"
    case Staging    = "Stg"
    case Dev        = "Dev"
}
```

You can also create an enum instance directly using the rawValue (which could come from NSUserDefaults) like:

```
let env = Environment(rawValue: "Dev")
```

You can extract the rawValue (String) from the enum object like this and then store it in NSUserDefaults if needed:

```
if let myEnv = env {
    println(myEnv.rawValue)
}


func saveEnvironment(environment : Environment){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(environment.rawValue, forKey: kSavedEnvironmentDefaultsKey)
}
```

Comment: And for those looking for the read... myEnv = Environment(rawValue: defaults.stringForKey(kSavedEnvironmentDefaultsKey))!

Comment: For anyone having issues with the `rawValue` initializer or property on your enum, make sure that your enum extends the type of your `rawValue`. For example, in OP's example, `Environment` extends `String`. I missed this the first time around.

Comment: Since you have no control about what is stored in preferences, you should check that defaults.stringForKey isn't nil, and in that case or if Environment ends up nil replace it with a default value.

Comment: If the type you extend is literal-convertible from either `String` or `Int`, you don't even need to define explicit raw values for each case, since they can be automatically assigned consistently with the type you extend: a string containing the case name for `String` enums; a progressive number for `Int`, `Float` and `Double` enums.

Comment: @AlexSmith, you still should use `.rawValue` (rather than `Int(...)` or `as Int`) when you want to access the underlying integer value. I was just saying that when you define your `ConnectionType` enum you don't need to explicitly assign an integer value to each case.

Comment: Lol, I just discovered that myself! Removed my comment too quickly!

Comment: In the case when you store Int rawValue to user defaults, user defaults will return 0 for no value, not nil. So may be you don't want your first Int rawValue start with 0.

Comment: I wonder if it's ok to store a hashValue in case your enum is not of type String or Int or any other type and thus no rawValue is possible. I guess the potential problem would be if you store a hashValue and meanwhile apple for some reason decide to change their hash function. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 25):

If you would like to save/read data from UserDefaults and separate some logic, you can do it in following way (Swift 3):

```
enum Environment: String {
    case Production
    case Staging
    case Dev
}

class UserDefaultsManager {

    static let shared = UserDefaultsManager()

    var environment: Environment? {
       get {
           guard let environment = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: kSavedEnvironmentDefaultsKey) as? String else {
               return nil
           }
           return Environment(rawValue: environment)
       }
       set(environment) {
           UserDefaults.standard.set(environment?.rawValue, forKey: kSavedEnvironmentDefaultsKey)
       }
    }
}
```

So saving data in UserDefaults will look this way:

```
UserDefaultsManager.shared.environment = Environment.Production
```

And reading data, saved in UserDefaults in this way:

```
if let environment = UserDefaultsManager.shared.environment {
    //you can do some magic with this variable
} else {
    print("environment data not saved in UserDefaults")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Using `Codable` protocol

Extent `Environment` enum that conforms to `Codable` protocol to encode and decode values as `Data`.

```
enum Environment: String, Codable {
    case Production
    case Staging
    case Dev
}
```

A wrapper for `UserDefaults`:

```
struct UserDefaultsManager {
    static var userDefaults: UserDefaults = .standard
    
    static func set<T>(_ value: T, forKey: String) where T: Encodable {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) {
            userDefaults.set(encoded, forKey: forKey)
        }
    }
    
    static func get<T>(forKey: String) -> T? where T: Decodable {
        guard let data = userDefaults.value(forKey: forKey) as? Data,
            let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            else { return nil }
        return decodedData
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
// Set
let environment: Environment = .Production
UserDefaultsManager.set(environment, forKey: "environment")

// Get
let environment: Environment? = UserDefaultsManager.get(forKey: "environment")
```

Comment: Does it also work when you have normal entries like strings, integers, ...?

Comment: Sure. They are primitive types and already conforms to `Codable`. Just try it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative that can be be easily used with enums based on types (like String, Int etc) that can be stored by NSUserDefaults.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct StoredProperty<T: RawRepresentable> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let rawValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T.RawValue, let value = T(rawValue: rawValue) else {
                 return defaultValue
            }
            return value
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
enum Environment: String {
    case Production
    case Staging
    case Dev
}

@StoredProperty("Environment", defaultValue: .Dev)
var storedProperty: Environment
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.1 You can create a generic property wrapper, using Codable to transform values in and out the UserDefaults

```
extension UserDefaults {
    // let value: Value already set somewhere
    // UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "foo")
    //
    func set<T>(_ value: T, forKey: String) where T: Encodable {
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(value) {
            setValue(encoded, forKey: forKey)
        }
    }

    // let value: Value? = UserDefaults.standard.get(forKey: "foo")
    //
    func get<T>(forKey: String) -> T? where T: Decodable {
        guard let data = value(forKey: forKey) as? Data,
            let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            else { return nil }
        return decodedData
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
public struct UserDefaultsBacked<Value>: Equatable where Value: Equatable, Value: Codable {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value
    var storage: UserDefaults = .standard

    public init(key: String, defaultValue: Value) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    // if the value is nil return defaultValue
    // if the value empty return defaultValue
    // otherwise return the value
    //
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            let value: Value? = storage.get(forKey: key)
            if let stringValue = value as? String, stringValue.isEmpty {
                // for string values we want to equate nil with empty string as well
                return defaultValue
            }
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            storage.set(newValue, forKey: key)
            storage.synchronize()
        }
    }
}

// use it
struct AppState: Equatable {
    enum TabItem: String, Codable {
        case home
        case book
        case trips
        case account
    }
    var isAppReady = false

    @UserDefaultsBacked(key: "selectedTab", defaultValue: TabItem.home)
    var selectedTab
    // default value will be TabItem.home

    @UserDefaultsBacked(key: "selectedIndex", defaultValue: 33)
    var selectedIndex
    // default value will be 33

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this type staging. Can you please try this it will help you.

```
enum Environment: String {
  case Production  = "Production URL"
  case Testing     = "Testing URl"
  case Development = "Development URL"
}
//your button actions
 // MARK: set Development api
  @IBAction func didTapDevelopmentAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let env = Environment.Development.rawValue
    print(env)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(env, forKey:Key.UserDefaults.stagingURL)
  }
// MARK: set Production api
  @IBAction func didTapProductionAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let env = Environment.Production.rawValue
    print(env)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(env, forKey:Key.UserDefaults.stagingURL)
  }

  // MARK: set Testing api
  @IBAction func didTapTestingAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let env = Environment.Testing.rawValue
    print(env)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(env, forKey:Key.UserDefaults.stagingURL)
  }
//Based on selection act
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "stagingURL") ?? "")")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1**
You can create property wrapper for this

```
@propertyWrapper final class UserDefaultsLanguageValue {
    var defaultValue: LanguageType
    var key: UserDefaultsKey

    init(key: UserDefaultsKey, defaultValue: LanguageType) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: LanguageType {
        get { LanguageType(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key.rawValue) as? String ?? defaultValue.rawValue) ?? .en }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: key.rawValue) }
    }
}

enum UserDefaultsKey: String {
    case language
}

enum LanguageType: String {
    case en
    case ar
}
```

And use it just like that

```
@UserDefaultsLanguageValue(key: .language, defaultValue: LanguageType.en) var language
```